# @SequenceGenerator, @GeneratedValue not working with auto increment primary key value with JPARepository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, db2, sequence-generators

I'm trying to save a new record from Spring Boot JPA. My DB2 database has already created sequence (My_Sequence) which has to be used for autoincrement (tried for all generation types)

I'm facing an issue while saving a new record, with code as below

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "My_Sequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "FIFAFIFT_SEQ1", sequenceName = "My_Sequence", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name="My_Column"),
```

Error:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error:
> SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=schemaName.My_sequence,
> DRIVER=4.24.92

Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 1):

`generator = "My_Sequence"` is not equal to `name = "FIFAFIFT_SEQ1"`

Example:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
    strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
    generator = "My_Sequence"
)
@SequenceGenerator(
    name = "My_Sequence",
    sequenceName = "mySeq",
    allocationSize = 5
)
private Long id;
```

Comment: I even tried the same value :) Sorry did not worked..

Comment: What is your target platform (Z/OS, i-series , Linux/Unix/Windows)?

Comment: Show me your application.properties or yml